# Public/Private Key encryption avoid MITM attack on a local network

Tags: networking, encryption, public-key-encryption

I have a sysem where I want to minimise outbound network communication to the internet. However, I need to ensure communication between local network clients and the local server is secure. I can't use HTTPS as an IP address is used. Also the locations where the servers are installed, the users will be non-technical, so no DNS configuration etc.. etc..

I'm hoping the following will be secure and only requires access to the internet on server/client initialization.

Is this open to attackers? (assuming the local server is secured and private key can not be extracted)

1. Server initializes, generates Pub/Private key pair. User signs
   into account with remote server which issues access token (JWT) for remote server (HTTPS). User creates local server account (Username/Password)
2. Local server uploads public key to remote server (HTTPS) using remote server access token.
3. Client initializes and discovers server
4. Server responds with server id
5. Client hits remote server with the server id (HTTPS) and gets the public key and stores it.
6. Client generates Pub/Private key.
7. Signs into local server account sending username/password/public-key envcypted with local server public key
8. Local Server issues access token (JWT) and stores
   client public key with that token. Any response to this access token is encrypted (body/headers) with client public key.
9. Client now communicates to local server with accesstoken and encryped headers/body with Local server public key.
10. Server responds to requests with body/headers encrypted with access token public key

Comment: Try here: https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a programming question.

Comment: One attack vector (there are lots more), is that a MITM when the client asks the server for it's ID could send back the ID of a server that an attacker controls.  The client then retrieves the public key for that server and sends it's username/password encrypted with the attackers public key...